# Access to each name of Person object in List<List<Person>> in one line in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8

Given List of List of Person, how to iterate through all the names in one line code without using forEach in java8? 
Please see the question in the comment in the code below.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<ArrayList<Person>> llist = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Person>>();

        ArrayList<Person> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
        list1.add(new Person("aaa"));
        list1.add(new Person("bbb"));

        ArrayList<Person> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
        list2.add(new Person("ccc"));
        list2.add(new Person("ddd"));

        llist.add(list1);
        llist.add(list2);

        // how to change this part into one line in java 8?
        llist.forEach(l -> {
            l.forEach(p -> {
                System.out.println(p.getName());
            });
        });

    }

    static class Person {
        String name;

        Person(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "" + this.name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*one line*"? It already looks like only one statement, you just wrote it across multiple lines for an improved readability. However you can indeed shorten that expression more, as shown by @Andremoniy. But beyond that I could not imagine how to further shorten it, besides *cheating* like creating an utility method that does the job for you. Then the call to the utility method is obviously one single small statement only...

Comment: What's the point of this exercise? If you REALLY want an one-liner, you can append all statements with `;`; what does that achieve?

Answer (score 4):

"One line" code without using forEach:

```
llist.stream().flatMap(Collection::stream).peek(System.out::println).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case you can simplify it to

```
    llist.forEach(l -> l.forEach(System.out::println));
```

(because `toString()` method of `Person` class returns essentially the same as `getName()`).

Answer (score 0):

without forEach, so something like this?

```
llist.stream().filter(ll -> {
        ll.stream().filter(l -> {
            System.out.println("do something on " + l);
            return true;
        }).toArray();

        return true;
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: That looks strange, but OP said "*without using `forEach`*", so could indeed be helpful...^^ But it does not shorten the expression, I think that was OPs original intend.

Comment: can't think of anything shorter than using forEach when it comes to iterating the list haha

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly useful but according to the requirement *without forEach*:

```
Iterator<String> iterator = llist.stream().flatMap(Collection::stream).map(Person::getName).iterator();  while(iterator.hasNext());
```

And not even a one liner as there is the cheat with putting the `while` on the same line.

The point here is to use the `flatMap(Collection::stream)` to flatten the `List<List<Person>>` into `List<Person>` and then to use the `map` to get the `name` out of the `Person`. From then on it pretty much depends what shall happen during the iteration, if it is a really `System.out.println` then nothing beats the `forEach`. Indeed, the `forEach` is then the only right thing to do. That would be then

```
llist.stream().flatMap(Collection::stream).map(Person::getName).forEach(System.out::println);
```